# Pom.xml file, manage relese and snapshot maven repository

Tags: java, git, maven, jenkins

In order to confiugre my Git Maven java project, I have a doubt about pom.xml and maven settings.
I have a Jenkins pipeline for dev branch. For this branch I need to deploy a SNAPSHOT artifact version on dedicated repository.
In another Jenkins pipeline I need to deploy release version.

Can I create a pom.xml that include all this configuration (in order to not change the pom.xml manually every time between branches)? In this case, how can automatically indicate the destination deploy repos?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use `<distributionManagement>` to set repos for SNAPSHOT and release.